# MongoDB - validating settings error

Tags: mongodb, mongoimport

I'm trying to import a CSV file into MongoDB using the following command;

```
mongoimport -db results --collection socialogy --type csv --file "F:\Projects\pandas\results.csv" --headerline
```

MongoDB gives the following error message;

```
error validating settings: incompatible options: --file and positional argument(s)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried removing double quotes?

Comment: @Astro, I did use single quotes and no quotes and had exactly the same error message.

Comment: how about  to place file in current path and then import..?

Comment: @Astro, I did `mongoimport -db results --collection socialogy --type csv --file "./results.csv" --headerline` and got the same error message. Replacing double quotes with single quotes or removing them completely still give the same error message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to have typo in your query. See *-db* option part, it should be *--db*. This way your really mix arguments as error message says.

Comment: I have even that written correctly, yet i get the same error

Comment: Could you post new question please with full description of your problem? This way it is hard to help you.

Comment: unfortunately, I am not allowed to post a new question for 5 months.

Comment: But I solved it, it was an issue with the csv file, the file apparently during conversion from excel, got a lot of junk values at the bottom.. and by a lot I mean a lot.. after I opened the csv and tried browsing to the bottom I realised this and deleted it and it worked fine. thanks :)